# Removing background with Open CV is not precise and some of pictures could not be done properly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to remove background from images using OpenCV. Majority of operations are succesfull but some pictures cant be processed properly. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
my code:

```
import os
import numpy 
import cv2
import os
import glob
img_dir = r"C:\Users\kaan\Documents\Plant_Seedlings_Classification-master\Plant_Seedlings_Classification-master\data\osmancik"
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
for f1 in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f1)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480)) 
    data.append(img)


data2 = []
arr = numpy.array(data2) 

for pict in data:

    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(pict, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    img_contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    img_contours = sorted(img_contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    for i in img_contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(i) > 100:
             break
    mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [i],-1, 255, -1)
    new_img = cv2.bitwise_and(pict, pict, mask=mask)
    name=randomString()+".jpg"
    path = r"C:\Users\kaan\Documents\Plant_Seedlings_Classification-master\Plant_Seedlings_Classification-master\segmentated\osmancik2"
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , name), new_img)
```

Image:

[image: Image Sample]

This is a good example:

[image: This is a good example]

This is a bad example:

[image: This is a bad example]

Comment: You rely on luminance, which is poor information compared to color. Try to threshold on saturation or hue.

Comment: I am new in image processing so I need some guide how to threshold on saturation or hue.

Comment: Convert to saturation or to hue and threshold.

Answer (score 2):

Use HSV filtering.

1. Change image colors from BGR to HSV (Hue Saturation Value).
2. Filter a certain range of saturation and hue.

Refer to this page for code https://pythonprogramming.net/color-filter-python-opencv-tutorial/